# How to get 2 fields out of 25 in Firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a website where I display products from Firestore. Each document has a fixed number of fields, which is 25. Can I query Firestore using TypeScript to not get the complete documents but only two fields, the product name and the price? I read that for iOS and Android you cannot. How about web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore client-side SDKs, including the one for browser/web clients, can only retrieve full documents.

Only Firestore's server-side/Admin SDKs have the option to retrieve a subset of the fields of a document.